# How many DWU/Azure are required for my existing process?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an existing server where my SQL server is hosted and I was planning to migrate this to a AZURE DW.

But for choosing the AZURE DW it was asking for DWU minimum (100) which is fine but I would like to know how to determine the DWU for the existing server ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The pricing comes from the Azure pricing calculator: SQL Data Warehouse, 100 DWU, $1,125/month SQL Data Warehouse, 500 DWU, $5,625/month [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/azure-sql-database/single/) is the link for the pricing calculation- which could help you estimate the cost as per your requirements.

> A vCore-based purchase model is best if you are looking for
> flexibility, control and transparency of individual resource
> consumption. This model allows you to scale compute, memory and
> storage based upon your workload needs and provides a straightforward
> way to translate on-premises workload requirements to the cloud.

**Note:**
*Azure SQL DW divides data into 60 "distributions." All 60 distributions are linked to one compute node if your DW is DWU100. 30 distributions are separated and reattached to a second compute node while scaling to DWU200. If you expand up to DWU2000, you'll have 20 compute nodes, each with three distributions. So you can see how DWU is a measure of your DW's compute/query power. As you scale, you'll have more computing per compute node working on less data.*

**UPDATE :**

There are still 60 distributions for Gen2, but the DWU calculation is somewhat different. DWU500c is a single full-size node with all 60 distributions installed (it serves as both a compute and a control node). Single nodes that are not full size are scales less than DWU500c (meaning fewer cores and less RAM than full size nodes on larger DWUs). The DWU1000c consists of two compute nodes, each having 30 distributions, and a separate control node. Three computing nodes and a separate control node make up the DWU1500c. The largest is DWU30000c, which consists of 60 compute nodes, each with its own distribution.